# How to retrieve FQDN of ActiveDirectory domain from the workstation with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, active-directory

How can I obtain the FQDN of the Active Directory domain a workstation is joined to, with nodejs?

For example, if I'm running nodejs on a windows workstation joined to the example.com domain, how do I actually get "example.com" from the system?

Comment: What is your current code that is not working? We can help debug non-working code, not writing it for you.